# Is it possible to get a list of printer names in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to create an automatic printer installer for Windows.

If I wanted to pull a list of printers, how would I go about that in Python? I know there's a way to get a list using a VB script on the command line, but that gives me additional information I don't need, plus there's no real good way to import the data into Python (that I know of)

The reasons for doing this is to get the values and put them in a list, and then have them check against another list. Anything in the one list will be removed. That ensures that the program won't install duplicate printers.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/)'s `win32print.EnumPrinters()` (more convenient), or invoke the `EnumPrinters()` API via the `ctypes` module (low dependency).

Here is a fully working `ctypes` version w/o error checking.

```
# Use EnumPrintersW to list local printers with their names and descriptions.
# Tested with CPython 2.7.10 and IronPython 2.7.5.

import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import BYTE, DWORD, LPCWSTR

winspool = ctypes.WinDLL('winspool.drv')  # for EnumPrintersW
msvcrt = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt  # for malloc, free

# Parameters: modify as you need. See MSDN for detail.
PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL = 2
Name = None  # ignored for PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL
Level = 1  # or 2, 4, 5

class PRINTER_INFO_1(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("Flags", DWORD),
        ("pDescription", LPCWSTR),
        ("pName", LPCWSTR),
        ("pComment", LPCWSTR),
    ]

# Invoke once with a NULL pointer to get buffer size.
info = ctypes.POINTER(BYTE)()
pcbNeeded = DWORD(0)
pcReturned = DWORD(0)  # the number of PRINTER_INFO_1 structures retrieved
winspool.EnumPrintersW(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, Name, Level, ctypes.byref(info), 0,
        ctypes.byref(pcbNeeded), ctypes.byref(pcReturned))

bufsize = pcbNeeded.value
buffer = msvcrt.malloc(bufsize)
winspool.EnumPrintersW(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, Name, Level, buffer, bufsize,
        ctypes.byref(pcbNeeded), ctypes.byref(pcReturned))
info = ctypes.cast(buffer, ctypes.POINTER(PRINTER_INFO_1))
for i in range(pcReturned.value):
    print info[i].pName, '=>', info[i].pDescription
msvcrt.free(buffer)
```

Comment: would you be able to provide an example of invoking a EnumPrinters() using ctypes in IronPython 2.7? I tried calling ctypes.EnumPrinters() and got an error. Thank you,.

Comment: Sure. Note that you can't call `EnumPrinters` directly, which is conditionally defined as `EnumPrintersA` or `EnumPrintersW`. My edited answer above uses `EnumPrintersW`.

Comment: Oh wow! This is pretty amazing. Thank you so much for such an elaborate answer. It works great. 
If I may ask one more question, and i will be on my way. Now that I have my available printer information I am also looking at one more thing, that is changing ADOBE PDF Printing Preferences and specifically the Adobe PDF Output Folder where all prints get dumped. I noticed in MSDN the PrinterProperties() method. Will that get me what I need?

Comment: Sorry that I'm not familiar enough with the printer API to give a sure answer here. As generic as the API was designed, I think it's uncommon to specify an output folder for a printing job, so it's likely an Acrobat thing. You may [configure the options](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1130786) with the official [Acrobat SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/overview.html), or, if you're brave enough, monitor and tweak some registry keys like [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Document_Imaging/Adobe_Acrobat/Q_23858934.html).